# Rehosting Windows Workflow Foundation Usage

Tags: workflow-foundation-4

I need to create an application to auto generate C code. ie. User can design the logic from the G-UI using basic blocks from C. This is similar to Matlab Code Generation. I need to do this using .net framework. When I search for the samples, I've seen about rehosting workflow foundation. I don't have any idea about WF4. Can you please anybody tell me is it possible to do the designer(Design is like flowchart) using WF4? And also I have seen some samples using MFC? I'm not sure which one can be applicable for my situation..

Answer (score 1):

I think you are confusing the Flowchart and Rehosted Workflow designer in WF  as some kind of UI to draw  the flowcharts.

Workflows are meant for executing business process and the different blocks like If-Else 
While etc help to implement a business logic.

Workflow Designer just provides a visual way of representing those if else / whiles etc so that developers and possible super users of the application can modify the business logic in a more visual manner instead of writing them using code.